# Simultaneous authorization in advanced app

Tags: php, authorization, yii2

In advanced app, I tried to implement divided authorization for backend and frontend.

In first case, I used `User` class from basic app, in order to use users without database. But for frontend part, I used User class from advanced app.

It would seemthat everything is working perfectly. But when you try to log in at the same time on both sides, the latter takes precedence over the previous one. Ie after entering the frontend parts - automatically eject the user from the backend and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set different cookies for frontend and backend in config/main.php file. For Eg.:

In backend:

```
'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'BACKENDID',   //Set name
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp', //create tmp folder and set path
        ],
    ],
```

In Frontend:

```
'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'FRONTENDID',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
        ],
    ],
```